# Oracle SQL Summing Values From Two Different Tables

Tags: oracle

Hey all so I am trying to add to (or subtract from) a column of different values based on a separate column in another table. Here is a example of what I am tying to do:

Table 1: (Current Inventory)

```
ItemName  |  Quantity
----------|----------
Baseball  |         5
Football  |        10
Jersey    |         3
```

Table 2: (New Shipment)

```
ItemName  |  Quantity
----------|----------
Baseball  |        70
Football  |       100
Jersey    |        50
```

How can I update my all items in Table 1 (current inventory) by adding Table 2's quantity to them?

Comment: Do you also require new inventory items to be inserted into the current table from the new table?

Comment: Is there a unique constraint on `ItemName`, in both tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE inventory i
   SET quantity = ( SELECT s.quantity+i.quantity 
                     FROM shipment s
                    WHERE s.itemname = i.itemname );
```

or a `MERGE`:

```
MERGE INTO inventory
USING 
(
  SELECT itemname, quantity
  FROM shipment
) ship ON (ship.itemname = inventory.itemname)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
    SET inventory.quantity = ship.quantity + inventory.quantity;
```

Example SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/82802/1) if you want to play.

Comment: Nice. The first may need adjustments, if the items appear multiple times in `shipment` (or none, so nulls will appear due to `SUM`). Something like: `SET quantity = quantity + COALESCE( ( SELECT SUM(s.quantity) FROM shipment s WHERE s.itemname = i.itemname ), 0);`